# Homothetic transformation

Tags: transformation, coordinate-systems

Suppose that, we have a homothetic transformation in a rectangular coordinate system, with center origin $(0,0)$ and $k$. This homothetic sends point $A(2,3)$  to point  $B(2x-1,x)$. My aim is to find $k$. First I have sketched the equation of line that goes through  the origin and point $(2,3)$ and it has the form:

$$y=3x/2.$$

Now I know that a homothetic does it (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Homothetic_transformation) which means that the point $(2x-1,x)$ is on  $y=3x/2$ and the line which goes through point $(2x-1,x)$ represented as $y=3x/2$ multiplied by $k$.

How can i solve the equation with both $x$ and $k$? Or should I simply take some value of x and solve it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $O(0,0)$ is the center of homothety and $k$ is its ratio, the point $A$ is sent to point $B$ according to the following equation:
$$B= O+k(A-O)$$
Substituting $A$ and $B$, we get:
$$(2x-1,x)=(0,0)+k(2,3)$$
Hence $x=3k$ and $2x-1=2k$.

Solving that system of equations, we get $k=\frac{1}{4}$ and $x=\frac{3}{4}$.